# Replace alphabet with random alphabet in bash/awk/sed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a file with below content

## cat input.txt

map: 022 HighValue2 **02ABC1232** PACKET v1.1

task: 022 HighValue2 **02ABC1232** PACKET v1.1

map: 023 LowValue3 **23ABCDe123** IP v1.3

task: 023 LowValue3 **23ABCDe123** IP v1.3

map: 024 MediumValue3452 **02ABwe12325** HOST v1.2

task: 024 MediumValue3452 **02ABwe12325** HOST v1.2

I want to replace the alphabets in bold letter which is in task line with any random alphabet without changing digits. For example the desired output should be

map: 022 HighValue2 **02hKQ1232** PACKET v1.1

task: 022 HighValue2 **02hKQ1232** PACKET v1.1

map: 023 LowValue3 **23wpNY123** IP v1.3

task: 023 LowValue3 **23wpNY123** IP v1.3

map: 024 MediumValue3452 **02QZNT12325** HOST v1.2

task: 024 MediumValue3452 **02QZNT12325** HOST v1.2

@karakfa, @Ed Morton and @Cyrus has given excellent answers. But awk version is not working in my case and the bash version is working fine. I want the updated bash version and working awk version for my updated input file.

I hope I am clear enough.

Comment: This is pretty easy in `perl` if you're open to that. I'm sure it's doable in some combination of bash/awk/sed, but I don't know them well enough to offer a solution without a lot of man page reading (because for similar tasks, I'd just use perl. :-) )

Comment: Are the letters in the middle section always next to each other?

Comment: @blm, You can post the answer in perl. By using perl code I can get some idea. But I am looking specially in bash/awk/sed.

Comment: @iismathwizard, yes alphabets are always next to each other.

Comment: @user3847894 well the regex you'd need is this: `task: \d{3} \w+ \d*([a-zA-Z]*)` You would just replace the contents of the capture group and it should work.

Comment: @EdMorton im sorry but i fail to see why that matters when i just simply said i was providing the regex. If this was an answer you would have a point.

Comment: @EdMorton i am not obligated to provide a complete answer in the comments. Otherwise they would be answers.

Comment: @EdMorton additionally, at 50k+ rep i would hope you're more computer savvy than to type a regular expression into a bash and expect something other than an error.

Comment: @EdMorton *"the regexp you provided, when used in any standard UNIX tool, will not match the desired string"*, are you so sure about that? `grep -P "task: \d{3} \w+ \d*([a-zA-Z]*)"` works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: @EdMoron For your comment to be useful, it'd have to be right.

Comment: "_updated input file_"? [Chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) alert!

Comment: @EdMorton What's truly astounding is how hard you have to press the issue. Why should I honestly give a shit? I made a comment. If this was an answer you would have a point.

Comment: @EdMorton you tend to write in a fashion that gave the impression of a condescending tone. Hence, my harsh backlash.

Comment: @EdMorton Apology accepted. Thank you for apologizing. I also apologize for my brash reaction. I saw this question when I didn't have a lot of time to write out a full answer. I figured I would at least contribute a regular expression that could help someone else with the full answer or would come back later when I had more time to dedicate to it. I agree that it's not particularly well suited to OP's environment (Unix) either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

array=({a..z} {A..Z})                     # all 52 possible characters

while read -r a b c d e; do               # loop with all lines of "file"
  echo -n "$a $b $c "
  for ((i=0;i<${#d};i++)); do             # loop with all characters of $d
    if [[ ${d:$i:1} =~ [a-zA-Z] ]]; then
      printf "%s" ${array[RANDOM % 51]}   # print random character from $array
    else
      printf "%s" ${d:$i:1}               # print current character
    fi
  done
  echo " $e"
done < file
```

Output with your file as input:

```
task: 022 HighValue2 02XeM1232 PACKET v1.1
task: 023 LowValue3 23lJBXx123 IP v1.3
task: 024 MediumValue3452 02Ochs12325 HOST v1.2
```

---

Update:

```
#!/bin/bash

array=({a..z} {A..Z})

while read -r a b c d e; do

  # additional part
  if [[ $a == "map:" ]]; then
    echo "$a $b $c $d $e"
    continue
  fi

  echo -n "$a $b $c "
  for ((i=0;i<${#d};i++)); do
    if [[ ${d:$i:1} =~ [a-zA-Z] ]]; then
      printf "%s" ${array[RANDOM % 51]}
    else
      printf "%s" ${d:$i:1}
    fi
  done
  echo " $e"
done < file
```

Output:

```
map: 022 HighValue2 02ABC1232 PACKET v1.1
task: 022 HighValue2 02Arb1232 PACKET v1.1
map: 023 LowValue3 23ABCDe123 IP v1.3
task: 023 LowValue3 23dRfWa123 IP v1.3
map: 024 MediumValue3452 02ABwe12325 HOST v1.2
task: 024 MediumValue3452 02cfdN12325 HOST v1.2
```

Comment: This script is working fine in debian machine. Can you tell me how can I print all the input file along with changes? I edited my questions and added few more lines. If I need to print other line as well do I have to use while loop two times?

Comment: Add a new line after `while`: `echo "$a $b $c $d $e"`

Comment: I updated my input file in my question. Earlier we were assuming that we have to process every line. So this script was working like a charm. But in my updated input file I don't want to process map: line. I just want to print map: line as it is but want to process only task: line. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: thanks Cyrus, it is working like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    lgth = split("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",new,"")
    srand()
}
{
    split($4,old,"")
    $4 = ""
    for (i=1;i in old;i++) {
        $4 = $4 (old[i] ~ /[[:alpha:]]/ ? new[int(rand()*lgth+1)] : old[i])
    }
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
task: 022 HighValue2 02bQh1232 PACKET v1.1
task: 023 LowValue3 23vxDXl123 IP v1.3
task: 024 MediumValue3452 02huyO12325 HOST v1.2

$ awk -f tst.awk file
task: 022 HighValue2 02AZk1232 PACKET v1.1
task: 023 LowValue3 23AHXkl123 IP v1.3
task: 024 MediumValue3452 02YYia12325 HOST v1.2
```

The above will work with GNU awk at least but there may be some awks that don't handle splitting on a NULL string by separating into characters so try it and see - there's other ways of populating the arrays or using strings instead, e.g. with any POSIX awk and most non-POSIX awks:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    new = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    lgth = length(new)
    srand()
}
{
    old = $4
    $4 = ""
    for (i=1;i<=length(old);i++) {
        $4 = $4 ( substr(old,i,1) ~ /[[:alpha:]]/ ? substr(new,int(rand()*lgth+1),1) : substr(old,i,1) )
    }
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
task: 022 HighValue2 02PeK1232 PACKET v1.1
task: 023 LowValue3 23zsyjH123 IP v1.3
task: 024 MediumValue3452 02XPtt12325 HOST v1.2
```

If that doesn't work you then you REALLY need to get a new awk as the one you are using is missing critical functionality but meantime - try changing the character class `[[:alpha:]]` to the character list `[a-zA-Z]` (or whatever character list contains only all the letters in your locale).

Comment: This script is working fine in GNU awk like you said but in my case it is not working. I am using Debian 7.2 and my awk version is mawk 1.3.3. I am getting the same output as input when running the script. This script is working fine in GAWK 4.0.2. What changes do I have to do to run this script in Debian with mawk 1.3.3?

Comment: I added a version that'll work in any awk.

Comment: The version you added is also not working in mawk 1.3.3. But it is working in GAWK.

Comment: Then your version of mawk is not POSIX compliant (which I believe was true of very old mawks). Given the standard features in my answer are missing from your awk and all you've told me is it's "not working" so there's no info to even start to debug, I'm afraid I can't help you as I have no idea what other standard features are missing but maybe you can understand my approach and use whatever functionality your awk does have to implement the same algorithm. One thing to try - change `[[:alpha:]]` to `[a-zA-Z]` as IIRC old mawk didn't support character classes.

Comment: thanks @Ed Morton, I will try the other approach. Your answer gave me enough clarity to find a solution in my own using mawk 1.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -f randomize.awk input1 
task: 022 HighValue2 02mpR1232 PACKET v1.1
task: 023 LowValue3 23hEkQj123 IP v1.3
task: 024 MediumValue3452 02zhtz12325 HOST v1.2
```

replace 4th field chars with random chars.

```
$ cat randomize.awk 

function r(k) { 
     s=""; 
     for(i=1;i<=k;i++) s = s substr(chars,rand()*n+1,1); 
     return s;
} 

BEGIN{
     chars="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; 
     n = length(chars)
}

{
     match($4, /([0-9]+)([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)/, a); 
     $4 = a[1] r(length(a[2])) a[3]
}

1
```

ps. Note that the random always uses the same sequence.  You can set it to a different sequence with `srand()` initiated perhaps with time stamp.

UPDATE: rewritten without match function

```
BEGIN{
   srand()
   chars="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
   n = length(chars)
}

{
   t="";
   for(j=1;j<=length($4);j++) {
      c = substr($4,j,1);
      r = substr(chars,rand()*n+1,1);
      t = t (c~/[a-zA-Z]/?r:c);
   }
   $4 = t;
   print
}
```

Comment: I am using Debian 7.2 and my awk version is mawk 1.3.3. I am getting syntax error in match line while executing above script. This script is working fine in GAWK 4.0.2. What changes do I have to do to run this script in Debian with mawk 1.3.3?

Comment: It's there to extract the alphabetical substring from the field, if your `awk` doesn't have `match`, you may need to substitute char by char while iterating over the field.

Comment: thanks for your solution. I will try with different approach.